# How to get the mail adress from the description attribute for a mail-merge PowerShell

Tags: powershell, split, powershell-2.0, mailmerge, powershell-ise

I've been trying to solve my problem for hours, checked the related topics but unfortunately found nothing. I need to send a merged-mail through PowerShell ISE. The only attributes I have is *Description* which's format is like this.

Position; FirstName.Lastname@company.com

I dont have the permission to create new attributes. Could anyone help me with the coding?

The email should start like this, but I can't even filter the mail address out of the description:
Dear Last Name First Name

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please read the help about asking [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, edit the question and fill in more details.

Answer (score 0):

your example has clear delimiters to split Position and mail address (;) and First- and Lastname from the mail address (. @) so you can easily split them apart.

```
$Description = "Position; FirstName.Lastname@company.com"

$MailAdress = $Description.Split(';')[1].Trim()
$FirstName = $MailAdress.Split('.')[0]
$LastName = $MailAdress.Split('@')[0].Split('.')[1]
```

Comment: As this answer has resolved your issue, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)